# pnpm is not installing the latest dependency when "latest" is specified

Tags: pnpm

`latest` is specified in my package.json, but it won’t get the latest.

```
pnpm list checkly
checkly 4.2.0
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/checkly, 4.4.0 has been out for 18 days.

It keeps installing 4.2.0 even after

```
pnpm store prune && rm -f pnpm-lock.yaml && pnpm i
```

---

If I specify `"checkly": "4.4.0",`, then it will install 4.4.0

Answer (score 0):

Looks like after upgrading to latest pnpm this was fixed

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to make sure all packages are up to date—regardless of ranges specified in `package.json`—is `pnpm up --latest`.

If you want to update a specific package use `pnpm up package-name@latest`

You can also specify in your `package.json`, which packages you want to keep up to date, and then use `pnpm up`.

```
// package.json

{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "package-name": "latest"
  }
}
```

*[Reference](https://pnpm.io/cli/update)*

Comment: How is specifying `"package-name": "latest"`, removing the lock file, and running `pnpm i` not sufficient?

Comment: Well, this *should* fetch the latest versions, but sometimes the lock file gets recreated with the previous versions due to compatibility or constraints from other dependencies. I'm not sure if that's what was happening to you. Still, using `pnpm up —latest` is a sure-fire way to update to latest, or use `pnpm up package-name@latest`.

Comment: Does `pnpm up —latest` write to `package.json`?

Comment: @KirkStrobeck Yes.